# JavaFX - How to run desktop app in the background using window close/minimize button and 'reopen or completely close' from hidden icons

Tags: javafx

I created a simple clipboard(desktop app) using JavaFX. Now I want to run the clipboard in the background when user minimizes or closes the app. For example, 'XAMPP' or 'μtorrent'. Of course, user can reopen or completely close the clipboard from hidden icons(in windows) or from the top panel(in ubuntu). From [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32355335/on-javafx-how-to-hide-stage-without-disposing-it-and-closing-the-application) question, i found

```
Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
```

which runs the clipboard in the background. But i want to show it in the hidden icons(in windows) so that i can reopen or completely close it from there.

I know how to get and modify the window OnCloseRequest. I just want to know what i should do to run the clipboard in the background.

I searched in the google and StackOverflow for any related tutorial or blog post but found nothing. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

I didn't share my code because my clipboard app has no problem. I just want to add the above-mentioned feature.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [On JavaFX, how to hide stage without disposing it and closing the application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32355335/on-javafx-how-to-hide-stage-without-disposing-it-and-closing-the-application)

Comment: I edited my question. Please look again and see if you can help. Thanks

Comment: I take it you want to use the system tray? Take a look at the linked questions in the possible duplicate—specifically https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626550/to-hide-javafx-fxml-or-javafx-swing-application-to-system-tray?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thank you, Slaw ... system tray is the thing, I was looking for :)