# Creating tray icon using JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, trayicon

I want to write a tray icon via `JavaFx`, but I only find that can write by `awt`.
Is there any way that can write it use `JavaFx`?

It will look like these tray icons from Windows 10:

[image]

Comment: Correct answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12571924/1624376)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If [this](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/e231e89e8d36ef4e5d8a)  is to be believed, JavaFX will feature tray icons in a future update. Till then stick to AWT. Keep track of the development using [this thread](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8092115) on the JDK bug system. Hope this helps.

Comment: Also if you can then sign into the JDK bug system and vote for the development to finish faster.

Comment: It is 2018 September and the issue is not still resolved.

Comment: It is 2020 in 2 days and the issue is still not resolved :)))

Comment: I we use to make the tray appearance like 'windows 10 style' what will be the workaround?

Comment: JavaFX is in maintenance mode. It only receives bugfixes and some small features to create an illusion that it's still alive. Don't expect JavaFX will ever receive tray support. They can't even implement i18n for standard components.

Answer (score 9):

If you'd prefer to not use AWT directly, I've created a small project `FXTrayIcon` which translates JavaFX MenuItems to AWT MenuItems and abstracts away all of the ugly AWT bits. It's at least a small help until JavaFX supports this natively.

See it on [my GitHub page](https://github.com/dustinkredmond/FXTrayIcon)

Comment: this library is awesome, but still It have issues in production environment, need to be fixed asap!

Comment: @CTO-AbidMaqbool we are actively working through any issues reported on the GitHub repository. If there's something that we need to be looking at, please create an issue there.

Answer (score 8):

You can't with pure JavaFX, but you can use AWT with JavaFX:

```
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.*;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

// Java 8 code
public class JavaFXTrayIconSample extends Application {

    // one icon location is shared between the application tray icon and task bar icon.
    // you could also use multiple icons to allow for clean display of tray icons on hi-dpi devices.
    private static final String iconImageLoc =
            "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/scafer31000/bubble-circle-3/16/GameCenter-icon.png";

    // application stage is stored so that it can be shown and hidden based on system tray icon operations.
    private Stage stage;

    // a timer allowing the tray icon to provide a periodic notification event.
    private Timer notificationTimer = new Timer();

    // format used to display the current time in a tray icon notification.
    private DateFormat timeFormat = SimpleDateFormat.getTimeInstance();

    // sets up the javafx application.
    // a tray icon is setup for the icon, but the main stage remains invisible until the user
    // interacts with the tray icon.
    @Override public void start(final Stage stage) {
        // stores a reference to the stage.
        this.stage = stage;

        // instructs the javafx system not to exit implicitly when the last application window is shut.
        Platform.setImplicitExit(false);

        // sets up the tray icon (using awt code run on the swing thread).
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(this::addAppToTray);

        // out stage will be translucent, so give it a transparent style.
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);

        // create the layout for the javafx stage.
        StackPane layout = new StackPane(createContent());
        layout.setStyle(
                "-fx-background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);"
        );
        layout.setPrefSize(300, 200);

        // this dummy app just hides itself when the app screen is clicked.
        // a real app might have some interactive UI and a separate icon which hides the app window.
        layout.setOnMouseClicked(event -> stage.hide());

        // a scene with a transparent fill is necessary to implement the translucent app window.
        Scene scene = new Scene(layout);
        scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        stage.setScene(scene);
    }

    /**
     * For this dummy app, the (JavaFX scenegraph) content, just says "hello, world".
     * A real app, might load an FXML or something like that.
     *
     * @return the main window application content.
     */
    private Node createContent() {
        Label hello = new Label("hello, world");
        hello.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 40px; -fx-text-fill: forestgreen;");
        Label instructions = new Label("(click to hide)");
        instructions.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 12px; -fx-text-fill: orange;");

        VBox content = new VBox(10, hello, instructions);
        content.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        return content;
    }

    /**
     * Sets up a system tray icon for the application.
     */
    private void addAppToTray() {
        try {
            // ensure awt toolkit is initialized.
            java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();

            // app requires system tray support, just exit if there is no support.
            if (!java.awt.SystemTray.isSupported()) {
                System.out.println("No system tray support, application exiting.");
                Platform.exit();
            }

            // set up a system tray icon.
            java.awt.SystemTray tray = java.awt.SystemTray.getSystemTray();
            URL imageLoc = new URL(
                    iconImageLoc
            );
            java.awt.Image image = ImageIO.read(imageLoc);
            java.awt.TrayIcon trayIcon = new java.awt.TrayIcon(image);

            // if the user double-clicks on the tray icon, show the main app stage.
            trayIcon.addActionListener(event -> Platform.runLater(this::showStage));

            // if the user selects the default menu item (which includes the app name),
            // show the main app stage.
            java.awt.MenuItem openItem = new java.awt.MenuItem("hello, world");
            openItem.addActionListener(event -> Platform.runLater(this::showStage));

            // the convention for tray icons seems to be to set the default icon for opening
            // the application stage in a bold font.
            java.awt.Font defaultFont = java.awt.Font.decode(null);
            java.awt.Font boldFont = defaultFont.deriveFont(java.awt.Font.BOLD);
            openItem.setFont(boldFont);

            // to really exit the application, the user must go to the system tray icon
            // and select the exit option, this will shutdown JavaFX and remove the
            // tray icon (removing the tray icon will also shut down AWT).
            java.awt.MenuItem exitItem = new java.awt.MenuItem("Exit");
            exitItem.addActionListener(event -> {
                notificationTimer.cancel();
                Platform.exit();
                tray.remove(trayIcon);
            });

            // setup the popup menu for the application.
            final java.awt.PopupMenu popup = new java.awt.PopupMenu();
            popup.add(openItem);
            popup.addSeparator();
            popup.add(exitItem);
            trayIcon.setPopupMenu(popup);

            // create a timer which periodically displays a notification message.
            notificationTimer.schedule(
                    new TimerTask() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() ->
                                trayIcon.displayMessage(
                                        "hello",
                                        "The time is now " + timeFormat.format(new Date()),
                                        java.awt.TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO
                                )
                            );
                        }
                    },
                    5_000,
                    60_000
            );

            // add the application tray icon to the system tray.
            tray.add(trayIcon);
        } catch (java.awt.AWTException | IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to init system tray");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Shows the application stage and ensures that it is brought ot the front of all stages.
     */
    private void showStage() {
        if (stage != null) {
            stage.show();
            stage.toFront();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, java.awt.AWTException {
        // Just launches the JavaFX application.
        // Due to way the application is coded, the application will remain running
        // until the user selects the Exit menu option from the tray icon.
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[code source](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/e231e89e8d36ef4e5d8a)

Comment: Thanks for your respond^^

Comment: This seems like a copy&paste from [this](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/e231e89e8d36ef4e5d8a), you should provide your sources when copying content!

Comment: ugh, java.awt is not supported in Netbeans FXML application on Java 14. Is this solution obsolete or am I just missing a setting somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

To make a system tray try following code:

Original document link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html

```
    //Check the SystemTray is supported
    if (!SystemTray.isSupported()) {
        System.out.println("SystemTray is not supported");
        return;
    }
    final PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu();

    URL url = System.class.getResource("/images/new.png");
    Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url);

    final TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image);

    final SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();

    // Create a pop-up menu components
    MenuItem aboutItem = new MenuItem("About");
    CheckboxMenuItem cb1 = new CheckboxMenuItem("Set auto size");
    CheckboxMenuItem cb2 = new CheckboxMenuItem("Set tooltip");
    Menu displayMenu = new Menu("Display");
    MenuItem errorItem = new MenuItem("Error");
    MenuItem warningItem = new MenuItem("Warning");
    MenuItem infoItem = new MenuItem("Info");
    MenuItem noneItem = new MenuItem("None");
    MenuItem exitItem = new MenuItem("Exit");

    //Add components to pop-up menu
    popup.add(aboutItem);
    popup.addSeparator();
    popup.add(cb1);
    popup.add(cb2);
    popup.addSeparator();
    popup.add(displayMenu);
    displayMenu.add(errorItem);
    displayMenu.add(warningItem);
    displayMenu.add(infoItem);
    displayMenu.add(noneItem);
    popup.add(exitItem);

    trayIcon.setPopupMenu(popup);

    try {
        tray.add(trayIcon);
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        System.out.println("TrayIcon could not be added.");
    }
```

Example system tray image in Windows 10

[image: System tray program example]

To invoke method of Javafx from awt event handler you may follw the following way:

```
yourAwtObject.addActionListener(e -> {
    Platform.runLater(() -> primaryStage.show());
});
```

Comment: Downvoted. This code won't stand on it's own. Author just copy pasted from a page.

Comment: Yes. I have used those code and given my working screenshot as well. I have also mentioned the link of that page. I have just posted here to help the people who stuck with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

i made it. JavaFX with AWT. I have one example of a application that shows and hides when you make left clic. i really hope works for you

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.SystemTray;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.TrayIcon;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.net.URL;
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainApp2 extends Application {

int stateWindow = 1;

@Override
public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {

    //Check the SystemTray is supported
    if (!SystemTray.isSupported()) {
        System.out.println("SystemTray is not supported");
        return;
    }

    URL url = System.class.getResource("/image/yourImage.png");
    Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url);

    //image dimensions must be 16x16 on windows, works for me
    final TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, "application name");

    final SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();

    //Listener left clic XD
    trayIcon.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
            if (event.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (stateWindow == 1) {
                            stage.hide();
                            stateWindow = 0;
                        } else if (stateWindow == 0) {
                            stage.show();
                            stateWindow = 1;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        }
    });

    try {
        tray.add(trayIcon);
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        System.out.println("TrayIcon could not be added.");
    }

    stage.setTitle("Hello man!");
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Say 'Hello man'");
    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Hello man!");
        }
    });
    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(btn);
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
    Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
    stage.show();

}

/**
 * The main() method is ignored in correctly deployed JavaFX application.
 * main() serves only as fallback in case the application can not be
 * launched through deployment artifacts, e.g., in IDEs with limited FX
 * support. NetBeans ignores main().
 *
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```