# JavaFX equivalent of Taskbar in Swing

Tags: java, windows, swing, javafx-8

I'm looking for the JavaFX equivalent of Swing [Taskbar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Taskbar.html) (aka TaskBarList3)

I've searched in the javafx documentation but i can't find it.

- Is the feature not available yet?
- There are alternative ways of
  achieving the same results?

I need to set the icon progress in the taskbar with JavaFX like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNXsm.jpg)

Comment: What does `java.awt.Taskbar::isSupported` say about the feature you want?

Comment: @CatalinaIsland the problem is the Taskbar is for Swing/AWT I'm looking for the same functionality in JavaFX

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*JavaFX app in System Tray*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12571329/261156). More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40571199/261156).